# How to convert lowercase string to uppercase and vice versa?

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a program which converts all uppercase  characters in a string to lowercase and lowercase characters to uppercase.For example if the string is "abcdE", it will return after coversion "ABCDe".
This is what I have tried so far

```
class String
    def is_upper?
        self == self.upcase
    end

    def is_lower?
        self == self.downcase
    end
end

s = gets.chomp

if s.length <= 100
    a = s.split(//)
    b, c = Array.new
    a.each do |m|
        if m.is_upper? 
            b.push(m.downcase)
        end
        if m.is_lower?
            b.push(m.upcase)
        end
    end
    c = b.join
end
```

However I can assess that this program is very erroneous.
I am still a novice learner. So forgive me if my solution program is very wrong.Please help me to find a correct and easier solution.

Comment: This looks very much like an assignment, and it would not be a fair and appropriate use of time for people to give you a solution.  How about you step back and think of some approaches without coding, just the logic? The coding can come after you've figured out the logic. Try to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As another pointed out, `swapcase` already exists, but I suspect it's something you're meant to implement on your own

Here's a functional approach

```
class String
  def is_upper?
    self == self.upcase
  end

  def is_lower?
    self == self.downcase
  end

  def head
    self[0]
  end

  def tail
    self[1..-1]
  end

  def swapcase
    if empty?
      ""
    elsif head.is_lower?
      head.upcase + tail.swapcase
    elsif head.is_upper?
      head.downcase + tail.swapcase
    else
      head + tail.swapcase
    end
  end
end

puts "abcdE".swapcase
#=> ABCDe
```

The looping pattern in `swapcase` is pretty obnoxious and should be decomposed out into a generic function

```
class String
  def is_upper?
    self == self.upcase
  end

  def is_lower?
    self == self.downcase
  end

  def head
    self[0]
  end

  def tail
    self[1..-1]
  end

  def map &f
    if empty?
      ""
    else
      yield(head) + tail.map(&f)
    end
  end

  def swapcase
    map do |x|
      if x.is_lower?
        x.upcase
      elsif x.is_upper?
        x.downcase
      else
        x
      end
    end
  end
end
```

It works the same but `swapcase` is a lot nicer now

```
puts "abcdE".swapcase
#=> ABCDe
```

Comment: Arguably, if the person is meant to implement it on their own then providing them with the code is not an appropriate approach :)

Comment: I see the ambiguity in my words now. I meant to imply "if you cannot rely on a built-in ruby method" ^_^ Either way, this implementation is one of many possible solutions. A learner can still benefit from it and find/make their own path with its help.

Answer (score 12):

No need to invent the wheel again.

There is already a method named `swapcase` in ruby to accomplish this.

For ex-

```
"Hello".swapcase          #=> "hELLO"
"cYbEr_PuNk11".swapcase   #=> "CyBeR_pUnK11"
```

You can find more details [here](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-swapcase)-

http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-swapcase

Comment: 2.3.1 is current, so when linking to documentation try and pin it to the most recent. There's sometimes some fun new stuff in there that will surprise you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this. I'll take care of this in future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way to do this:

```
s = "abcdE"

new_val = s.chars.map do |c| 
    if c.upcase != c  then 
        c.upcase 
    elsif (c.downcase != c) then
        c.downcase
    else
        c
    end
end.join

p new_val
#=> ABCDe
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"ábcdE".gsub(/./) do |c|
  case c
  when /\p{Lower}/ then c.upcase
  when /\p{Upper}/ then c.downcase
  else c
end
#⇒ "ÁBCDe"
```

Refer to [`Regexp` character properties](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Properties) for further explanation.

Answer (score -5):

The logic should be something like this.
1. You iterate over the characters in the String.
2. If the Character's ASCII code is between 97 and 122 (inclusive), then it is uppercase, so subtract 32 from it and store the new char in output character Array.
3. If the Character's ASCII code is between 65 and 90 (inclusive), then it is lowercase, so add 32, and store in the output character.
4. If the character is anything else, you may just leave it, or depends on the ask.
5. Convert charArray to String and output.

Code in JAVA

```
    private static String convert(String input){
    //upper case 65 to 90, inclusive
    //lower case 97 to 122, inclusive
    char[] output = new char[input.length()];
    int index = 0;
    for(char ch: input.toCharArray()){
        if((int)ch>=97 && (int)ch<=122){
            //upper case character in the String 
            ch = (char) (ch - 32);
            output[index]=ch;
        }else if((int)ch>=65 && (int)ch<=90){
            //lower case character in the String
            ch = (char) (ch + 32);
            output[index]=ch;
        }else{
            //assuming any other character is remained untouched
            output[index]=ch;
        }
        index++;
    }
    return String.valueOf(output);
}
```

Comment: i suspect that you were downvoted for assuming that the string was ASCII, and providing code in Java for a question tagged as Ruby

Comment: hmmm ok !! I will be careful going forward.